# powershell, difference between [object[]]::new(10) and new-object object[] 10

Tags: powershell

I have a strange behavior that I don't understand. are not all array created equal?

```
$a1=[object[]]::new(15)
$a1.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

$a1.length
15

0..14|%{$a1[$_]=$_}
```

string formatting with the 10th element works as expected.

```
'{10}' -f $a1
10
```

but...

```
$a2=new-object object[] 15
$a2.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


$a2.length
15

0..14|%{$a2[$_]=$_}
```

the very same string formatting request raise an error as if the `$a2` array was too small

```
'{10}' -f $a2
Erreur lors de la mise en forme d’une chaîne : L'index (de base zéro) doit être supérieur ou égal à zéro et inférieur à la taille de la liste des arguments..
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ '{10}' -f $a2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : ({10}:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError
```

am I missing something? where am I wrong?

Comment: I don't have an explanation, just a workaround: `'{10}' -f @($a2)`

Comment: I don't have explanation, but your code does not like "PowerShell style" to me. "Usually" arrays are created from output of output of other commands like `$a3 = @(0..14)` or `$a4 = Get-Service -Name X*`. 
Common ways to work with arrays: https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays

Comment: @MikeSh I know. but I have a huge composite format string which contains many format items (~40). the array contains the replacement values. I allocate its and then fill it with computed values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is a **known bug**:

Because [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) is a *cmdlet* (command) rather than an *expression* (such as `[object[]]::new(15)`), its output object is wrapped in a [`[psobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject) instance.

Usually, these invisible `[psobject]` wrappers are *benign*, and the wrapper presents as if it were the wrapped object itself.

*Situationally*, however, the presence of such a wrapper interferes with functionality, such as in your case:

The `-f` operator doesn't recognize a `[psobject]`-wrapped array as such, which causes the problem you saw:

To simulate the problem with an array artificially wrapped in `[psobject]`:

```bash
# !! Error:
#  "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and 
#   less than the size of the argument list."
# The [psobject]-wrapped array is treated as a *single* object so -f
# sees no *2nd* value ({1})
# Omitting the [psobject] cast works as expected.
'{1}' -f [psobject] ('a', 'b')

# Ditto, with New-Object, 
# which *invariably and implicitly* returns the array in a [psobject] wrapper.
'{1}' -f (New-Object string[] 2)
```

Relevant GitHub issues:

- [GitHub issue #14355](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14355): The bug at hand.
- [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579): General discussion and other cases where the situational `[psobject]` wrapping causes problems.

---

**Workarounds:**

- As you've noted, using a constructor *expression*, via the [intrinsic static `::new()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members?view=powershell-7.4#new-method-for-types) PowerShell exposes on all .NET types (which requires v5+ of PowerShell) - such as `[object[]]::new(15)` - does *not* exhibit the problem, because no invisible `[psobject]` wrapper is then involved.

  - Given that this method is more efficient and uses the familiar method syntax used in constructor calls, it is worth preferring it to `New-Object` in general.
- In PowerShell v4-, use `.psobject.BaseObject` to work around the problem, via the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views), which returns the wrapped array:

  ```bash
  $a2 = (New-Object object[] 15).psobject.BaseObject
  '{10}' -f $a2  # OK
  ```